# RDS unable to connect to local machine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I created simple free tier RDS instance for mysql connection testing from local. i made sure `Public accessibility` is `yes`
created inbound rule as this (all traffic for all ports from anywhere)

```
> sgr-052bd15d02d6f0xxx –   All traffic All All sg-857778f1 
> sgr-085e08ad1f482xxxx IPv6    All traffic All All ::/0    for sqlyog
```

then i ran following command

```
mysql -h database-1.czzsgxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p 
(entered password)
```

but it doesn't connects and gives following error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database-1.czzsgzotg0i1.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
```

Now i've researched a lot and found out that this problem gets fixed only by changing the inbound rule for db but in my case its still not working(also i've tried other inbound rules but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you wanting to connect from an Amazon EC2 instance, or from your own computer on the Internet?

Comment: from my own computer on the internet @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Does it fail to connect immediately, or does it take a few seconds before showing the error message?

Comment: it takes a while then shows that error

Comment: Taking 5+ seconds before failing is an indication that there is no communication (typically caused by incorrect Security Group configuration), rather than being rejected due to a bad password.

Comment: most probably yes but im unable to make a rule that will work for me yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to connect from your own computer on the Internet to the Amazon RDS instance, the Security Group needs an **Inbound rule** for:

- Port: 3306
- Source: *Your IP address*

Looking at your current rules:

```
> sgr-052bd15d02d6f0xxx –       All traffic All All sg-857778f1 
> sgr-085e08ad1f482xxxx IPv6    All traffic All All ::/0    for sqlyog
```

The first line is only accepting incoming connections from Security Group `sg-857778f1`. The second line is for IPv6.

Comment: i tried changing my rule for my ip and it recommended me some ip by default and when im using that ip it gives error and doesnt let me save the settings 
the error is following : You may not specify an IPv4 CIDR for an existing IPv6 CIDR rule.

Comment: also i think is it necessary to change it to my ip when i can change it to any ip in case my ip is changed ill have to change it everytime in the rule

Comment: You appear to be editing a rule for IPv6. If this is a **new** security group that you created for your RDS instance, then remove all rules and add the rule I recommend above. If this is the **Default** security group, then I recommend that you do _not_ change it. Instead, **Create a new security group**, add the Inbound rule I recommend, then add this new security group to the RDS instance and remove the existing security group.

Comment: Yes, if your IP address changes, you would need to change the rule. This gives you _much_ better security than opening the database to then entire Internet, which is bad security practice. However, it is your choice -- you can open it to `0.0.0.0/0` if you are willing to take the risk.

Comment: i created a new security group like u said and it worked.